# How to find out the frechet derivative of the following non linear function?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, frechet-derivative

The given operator is $$F: D(F) = \{c \in L^2[0,1] :  c \geq 0 \ a.e. \} \to L^2[0,1]$$ $$F(c) = u(c)$$ where $u$ is the solution of $$-u_{xx} + cu = f, \quad f \in \ L^2[0,1]$$ Now for $c \in D(F)$  let $$A(c) : H^2 \cap H_0^1 \to L^2$$ be defined by $$A(c) \phi = -\phi_{xx}+c \ \phi$$ Then we have $$F(c) = u(c) = A(c)^{-1}f$$ Note that $H^2$ is Sobolev space i.e. $$H^2(U) = W^{2,2}(U) \quad \& \quad H_0^1 = \overline{C_c^{\infty}(U)}$$ i.e. closure of the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $U$. Closure is taken in $W^{1,2}(U)$. Now my problem is to find the first frechet derivative of $F$. This is given by $$F'(c)h = -A(c)^{-1}(hu(c))$$ But I am unable to find it. I start with definition but strucked in the beginning.

Comment: 1. In the definition of $H_0^1$, you should take the closure w.r.t. the norm in $H^1$, not $H^2$. 2. Your $D(F)$ is not open (and does not have any interior point). Hence, the Fréchet derivative is not well defined. 3. Typically, such questions can be answered with an implicit function theorem.

Comment: @grew This closure i have written is definition given in Evans Partial differential equation book, chapter-5.

Comment: This is not true. See the definition on p. 245 (section 5.2.2).

Comment: Yes you are right, I made the change.

Comment: i have some more information now, $A(c)$ is Linear, so does $A(c)^{-1}$, now i reached to the point $$F(c+h)-F(c) = -A(c+h)^{-1}(hu(c))$$ How to go further now as i can see i am very close to the answer now.